# How do I animate my camera in unity in first person to have head bobbing while walking + running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, camera

After I did the Brackey's FPS movement tutorial, I have added a sprint mechanic and have thought how do I add camera bobbing in this specific case. Most of the videos either don't work or don't have the way I want to add it.

What I want to do is I want to add an animation but still look around with the camera. Instead of doing the movement like in the videos I want to move it in another way (as shown in the picture).
[I want to do the movement from side to side, not up and donw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE3XT.png)

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    public Camera cam;

    public int MaxFOV = 90;
    public float timeFOV = 0.03f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float s = Input.GetAxis("Fire3") + 1;

        if(s == 2)
        {
            cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(cam.fieldOfView, MaxFOV, timeFOV);
        }
        else
        {
            cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(cam.fieldOfView, 60, timeFOV);
        }

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z * s;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Here's how the player is organized:
[Player organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yatQq.png)

Sorry if it was too long, it's my first post here.

Answer (score 1):

This step is important: change your code for the controller to only move an  empty gameObject instead of the camera. Then you should put the camera as a child of that empty game object.

If you are not familiar with a sine wave, it basically goes up and down in a smooth way. [Image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Simple_sine_wave.svg)

In my mind, I would want to the player's head to bob faster and higher the faster they go.

you can play around with [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/czpshqnqcl) I made.

To get the speed someone is going, get the .magnitude of your velocity vector.

Put something like this in your script:

**Note: cam is the child of your empty parent game object. cam should only be controlled here, and the parent of cam should be rotated in the other parts of your script.**

```
public float bobSpeed;
public float bobHeight;

GameObject cam;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 speed = velocity.magnitude;
    float sin = bobHeight * Mathf.sin(bobSpeed * speed);
    cam.transform.position = Vector3.up * sin;
}
```

Note: `bobHeight` is "b" in [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/czpshqnqcl), and `bobSpeed` is "a".

---

**Edit:**

If you would like to stop bobbing for slow speeds, add an if statement, and check if sin is lower than bobMargin, and Lerp it down to 0.

```
public float bobMargin;
public float bobMarginSpeed;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 speed = velocity.magnitude;
    float sin = bobHeight * Mathf.sin(bobSpeed * speed);

    if (sin < bobMargin)
    {
        sin = Mathf.Lerp(sin, 0, Time.deltaTime * bobMarginSpeed);
    }

    cam.transform.position = Vector3.up * sin;
}
```

**Let me know of any problems in the comments** thanks.

Comment: Wait, i have an update.

Comment: I put this code in the last part in the update section:
63        Vector3 speedness = velocity.magnitude;
64        float sin = bobHeight * Mathf.Sin(bobSpeed * speedness);
65        cam.transform.position = Vector3.up * sin;

But it says:
Assets\PlayerMovement.cs(63,29): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'
Assets\PlayerMovement.cs(64,43): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'
I changed vector3 to float and it had no errors, but the camera just sticked to the bottom of the character